# Detailed dataflow in hadoop's mapreduce?

Tags: java, memory, hadoop, mapreduce

I am struggling a bit to understand the dataflow in mapreduce. Recently a very demanding job crashed when my disks ran out of memory in the reduce phase. I find it difficult to estimate how much disk my job will need. I will describe the dataflow in detail.

**It would be helpful if someone could correct, elaborate on the data flow in mapreduce or give advice on dimensioning my system.**

### **CLUSTER CONFIGURATION:**

I have a cluster containing **30 slaves** with

- 12 GB RAM
- 100 GB hard disk
- 4 cores

My **map tasks** are very similar to wordcount, so they need little memory. My **reduce tasks** work with permutation groups of words. Since identical words need to be joined the reduce function requires a temporary hash map which is always <= 3GB.

Since I have 12GB of RAM and my hadoop daemons require 1GB of heap + 500MB for the operating system I divided the map/reduce slots as follows:

**4 map slots with 900MB heap** and **2 reduce slots with 3GB heap**. Since the map slots do not require more than 300MB of memory I have set `io.sort.mb` to 500 MB to improve the in memory sort in the map phase.

My job has **1800 map tasks** each generating 8 GB of map output. Since I use BZIP2 for compression this can be compressed to 1 GB. This means that the total **map output will be below 2 TB** while I have 3 TB of memory.

I have chosen 100 reduce tasks each generating 5 GB of output.

At first sight everything should fit in memory. But obviously the sorting phase requires compression and decompression, and the copy phase requires the data to be at 2 places at the same time (I assume). So here is where it gets tricky, that's why I would like to fully understand the data flow. This is how I think it works, but please correct me if I am wrong:

### DATA FLOW

A map tasks generates a number of **spills** (200 in my case) which are **sorted** in memory and then **compressed** before they are written to the local disk. Once the map task finishes this gives me 200 spill files which are **merged** per 10 (`io.sort.factor`).
This implies that 10 files are **decompressed**: 10 x (5MB -> 40MB), so this gives 0.4GB of **compress/decompress overhead**. Although I am not sure what happens after the 200 spills had their first merge round. I suppose they are shuffled first per reduce task? So the files wouldn't really increase much in size.
If we look at this from a blackbox point of view it means we start with 200 compressed spills and we end up with 100 compressed files for the reduce tasks (1 per task).

Since I only have 60 reducers, now per node **60 compressed files are copied to the reducers**, this is already done during the map phase. This probably implies that the **compressed files exists temporarily on both source and destination**. This implies that in this case the memory requirements go up (temporarily) 160 compressed files per node which is 1.6 times the map output. The **map output is 1800 GB** so, we end up with 2880 GB albeit temporarily. So the first reduce phase should be able to start and it does. After copying (I hope!) the **data is removed from the mappers local output directory** so we have the same amount of data as there is map output, being 1800 GB again.

Now the sort phase in the reducers starts. I hope it doesn't start before the memory of the mappers is cleared?! Since to merge the output of the 1800 map tasks, it has to be decompressed. The **input of a reduce task** is approximately mapoutput / 100 = 18 GB of compressed data. Now how is this decompressed, **it cannot be decompressed all at once** since I would have 144GB per node then, and since my job didn't crash then the decompression is performed slightly smarter. I would think in the same way as in the map phase: 10 files (of 1800 task outputs) are decompressed and merged at the same time. The decompression would then give an overhead of 18GB/180 = 100 MB per merge round. The question again is **how the last merge rounds happens**, I remember reading in the hadoop reference that the reducers do not keep merging until there's only one file left.

After the sorting in the reduce phase the reduce phase runs which requires the decompression of the input records but since every reduce task works with 500 input key groups this should not be a real issue.

As mentioned before the reduce tasks generate approximately 5GB of output to the DFS (0.5TB in total).

The job really gets into trouble after the first 60 reduce tasks finishes. In the second round the tasks start to crash during the sort phase, which makes me think it has to do with copying overhead or decompression overhead.

The precise exception is: `org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for attempt_201310160819_0001_r_000068_1/intermediate.3`

I hope I explained my program flow in sufficient detail as well as my understanding of mapreduce. I would be really thankful if :

- someone could clear up the smoke concerning the copy phase and the merging phases
- as well as providing suggestions to overcome the job crash.
- It would be ideal for me to be able to **estimate precisely how much memory I will need** since it would be unpleasant if I tried a cluster with 40 nodes to have a crash after 5 days of operation (as experienced this time), since **deadlines** are getting close.

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

### The stacktrace for my job failure is here:

Exception 1:

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for attempt_201310160819_0001_r_000068_1/intermediate.3
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Merger.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Merger.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier.createKVIterator(ReduceTask.java:2539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier.access$400(ReduceTask.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Exception 2:

```
FAILEDjava.io.IOException: Task: attempt_201310160819_0001_r_000075_1 - The reduce copier failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/map_1622.out
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapOutputFile.getInputFileForWrite(MapOutputFile.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$InMemFSMergeThread.doInMemMerge(ReduceTask.java:2798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$InMemFSMergeThread.run(ReduceTask.java:2762)
```

Exception 3: (probably caused by the diskchecker exception)

```
Task attempt_201310160819_0001_r_000077_1 failed to report status for 2400 seconds. Killing!
```

Comment: correction to data flow from mapper: they are first partitioned per reduce task and then sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an email from Praveen Sripati referring to the hadoop reference, I will paste it here:

> **During the copy phase, does the data exist on both map and reduce task? When is the map output cleared?**
>
> The below is from the Hadoop - The Definitive Guide
>
> Hosts do not delete map outputs from disk as soon as the first reducer
>   has retrieved them, as the reducer may subsequently fail. Instead,
>   they wait until they are told to delete them by the jobtracker (or
>   application master), which is after the job has completed.

This is very important, the map output remains on disk!! A little bit unfortunate in my case.

> 5) **Then the merging in the reducers starts. Not completely sure how it is done. Does it merge to one file per reduce key? Or does it merge everything for a single task?**
>
> Again from the same book
>
> When all the map outputs have been copied, the reduce task moves into
>   the sort phase (which should properly be called the merge phase, as
>   the sorting was carried out on the map side), which merges the map
>   outputs, maintaining their sort ordering. This is done in rounds. For
>   example, if there were 50 map outputs and the merge factor was 10 (the
>   default, controlled by the io.sort.factor property, just like in the
>   map’s merge), there would be five rounds. Each round would merge 10
>   files into one, so at the end there would be five intermediate files.
>
> Thanks, Praveen

This implies that the number of files after merging is limited to io.sort.factor. In my case there are 10 segments, 1.8GB each. During the last merge everything had to be decompressed so 1.8 * 10 GB was required during each round = 18 GB.

Comment: A solution for me could be to change the `mapred.local.dir` to an external storage (we have a mounted share on the cluster). The drawback is that during the sort phase the network will be needed to transfer the data, but on the plus side the DFS will have plenty of room to do the rest of the job.